# How to identify exactly what whitespace?

Tags: php, html

I am writing a php script to dissect information copied from an external webpage.

I paste the external data into a text area, which is passed through PHP's post function.

One of the lines looks something like this:

972 Date Name Information

The issue is, the first space after "972" is not actually a space.  When I execute the strpos function with needle " ", it returns the position of the space following "Date".  Possible solutions are:

- Execute strpos which searches for all possible whitespaces.
- Find some way to make my browser echo out the actual whitespace code so I know what to enter for the needle.

Suggestions?

Comment: for what purpose, exactly? if you want to remove it, just use `trim()`.

Comment: I need to use it as a delimiter.  As in search for the position, then execute the substr function to capture the information before the "space"

Comment: @Tortooga how about doing a preg_split then by more than just whitespace?

Comment: that would be reinventing the wheel. have you heard of `explode()`?

Comment: If I explode on delimiter " ", it does not separate on that point.  Again, there is a space in the line which looks like a space but is not actually " ", and I need to figure out what exactly the whitespace is.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.  The space character is apparently "\xA0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regular Expression to intercept any character that is a whitespace of any kind, plus chr(160) to intercept non-breaking space. This should work:

```
$str = "972 Date Name Information";

if (preg_match_all('/[\s'.chr(160).']/', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {

   print_r($matches);
}
```

It should give you the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => �
                    [1] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>  
                    [1] => 8
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>  
                    [1] => 13
                )

        )

)
```

where the numbers at index [1] are the positions of the various whitespace characters in the string.

Comment: Interestingly, all it returned was the 8th position.  It still doesn't recognize the other spaces.  (By the way, I have since figured out that those spaces are char(160) spaces)

Comment: It is the non-breaking space character. See here: http://www.adamkoch.com/2009/07/25/white-space-and-character-160/

Comment: I've edited the reply so that it includes this character in the Regular Expression

Comment: Thank you.  By the way, someone else posted here (then deleted the post) suggesting to use PHP's "ord" function.  This spits out the ASCII value of the stubborn character.  I used this to discover the space was actually char(160)

Comment: The above Regular Expression should cover most cases, if it does not you can try and add /u at the end /[\s'.chr(160).']/u to make it UTF-8 compatible. It should catch everything that is considered and known as whitespace.